# querieng document which doesn't have a given field or is empty string in Solr

Tags: node.js, solr

I am doing a query with solr where I need to find documents without a given field say 'name' and I am trying following part;

```
$q=+status:active -name:["" TO *]'
```

But it sends both all the documents with and without that field.

Can anyone help me figure this out?
the field name is a normal String type and is indexed.
I am using nodejs. Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax):

> `-field:[* TO *]` finds all documents without a value for field

### Update

> I tried it but it sends even the ones with the field non empty

Then my wild quess is that you are using search query `q` instead of using filter query `fq`. Since you are using multiple statements in query I assume that `q` does some extra magic to get the most relevant documents for you, which can lead to returning some non-wanted results.
If you want to get the strict set of results you should use filter query `fq` instead, [see docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq).

Comment: I tried it but it sends even the ones with the field non empty

Comment: @SumanLama, it can be caused by using `q` instead of `fq`. See my update to answer